# Delete documents from ElasticSearch index in python

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

Using [elasticsearch-py](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py), I would like to remove all documents from a specific index, without removing the index. Given that `delete_by_query` was moved to a separate plugin, I want to know what is the best way to go about this?

Comment: You can't just delete and recreate the index?

Comment: @cricket_007 I could, but I'd rather do it by removing the documents. Otherwise, I'd have to check the index settings and mappings and use them when recreating index. I think it's easier to remove the documents.

Comment: A simple backup of the mappings and such shouldn't be that difficult. A full index scan and a bulk delete doesn't seem "easier", IMO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Scroll/Scan API call to gather all Document IDs and then call batch delete on those IDs. This is the recommended replacement for the Delete By Query API based on [the official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/docs-delete-by-query.html).

**EDIT**: Requested information for using this specifically in elasticsearch-py. Here is the documentation for the [helpers](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/helpers.html). Use the Scan helper to scan throgh all documents. Use the Bulk helper with the delete action to delete all the ids.

Comment: Can you provide more information about how to do this in elasticsearch-py?

Comment: Added a link to the specific docs for the Python helpers you need to perform the scan and then call the bulk deletion. Everything you need should be there!

Answer (score 2):

It is highly inefficient to delete all the docs by delete by query. More direct and correct action is:

- Getting the current mappings (Assuming you are not using index templates)
- Dropping the index by `DELETE /indexname`
- Creating the new index and the mappings.

This will take a second, former will take much, much  more time and unnecessary disk I/O

Comment: Thank you. It's what I did in the end. I'll leave the other answer as accepted, since it answers the question more directly (even if it is the wrong approach).